# Multi-axis line chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, yaxis

The following code I tried to display two y-axis on the line chart and I added `yAxisID` in both the data source. However, it is nothing to shown. May I know what's wrong with my code? Thank you.

```
function BuildChart(labels, valuesa, valuesb, chartTitle) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Temperature',
        fill: false,
        data: valuesa,
        yAxisID: 'y1',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderColor: 'red',
      }, {
        label: 'Relative Humidity',
        fill: false,
        data: valuesb,
        yAxisID: 'y2',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderColor: 'blue',
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        y1: {
          type: 'linear',
          display: true,
          position: 'left',
          },
        y2: {
          type: 'linear',
          display: true,
          position: 'right',
        },
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: false,
              labelString: ''
            }
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
            display: false,
            labelString: '',
          }
        }]

      }
    }
  })
  return myChart;
};


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(this.response);

    // Map json labels  back to values array
    var labels = json.feed.entry.map(function(e) {
      return e.gsx$tag.$t;
    });

    // Map json values back to values array
    var valuesa = json.feed.entry.map(function(e) {
      return e.gsx$dailytemperature.$t
    });

    // Map json values back to values array
    var valuesb = json.feed.entry.map(function(e) {
      return e.gsx$dailyrh.$t
    });

    BuildChart(labels, valuesa, valuesb, "Temperature", "Relative Humidity");
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/", false);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the chart `options` of your code, there are too many definitions of `yAxes` (before and after `xAxis`).

To make it work, the entire chart `options` can basically be reduced to what you see below.

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left',
        id: 'y1',
      },
      {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        },
        id: 'y2',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> For further information, please consult [Create Multiple Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#creating-multiple-axes) from the
>   Chart.js documentation.